# how to register eureka services un Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, netflix-eureka

I have set up a microservice environment with kubernetes and a.o. eureka. The problems is that services get registered with the pod name and the clients try to access them directly and not with the kubernetes service. That's what I see in the eureka dashboard:

```
SERVICE-USERS   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - service-users-1822504684-9b688:service-users:8501
```

Consequently, feign calls to that service fail with `java.net.UnknownHostException: service-users-1822504684-9b688`

Is there a way to make the eureka/kubernetes combination work? I understand that I could scrap eureka and let the clients talk to the kubernetes service directly.

A bit more info:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
service-users-1822504684-9b688   1/1       Running   0          1h

$ kubectl get svc
NAME            CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service-users   10.0.0.119   <none>        8501/TCP    3d
```

Comment: This sounds like a possible duplicate of [Eureka and Kubernetes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567429/eureka-and-kubernetes) ... you might want to provide some more details on how you configured your services / eureka.

Comment: I saw this: both answers advise to set up a service. That's what happens with a service.

Comment: As said before, maybe some details for the eureka configuration would be a good addition for your question...

Comment: Which details would you wish to see?

Comment: From reading a little into it, it seems that eureka uses some discovery configuration - that's maybe worth sharing

Comment: The service is registered with an unreachable pod name, so I guess no discovery configuration could help from this point. The whole client config (using spring-cloud-starter-eureka) is this one property: eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server/eureka/, eureka-server being the kubernetes eureka service name.