# Can I use Netflix Eureka with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am deploying a microservice application in kubernetes cluster. And one of the services it has is Neflix Eureka for service discovery.

My Question :
Is it possible to deploy Neflix Eureka from kubernetes? Because if the other Pods try to register themselves with eureka then the Pod IP is registered with Eureka which is wrong I think, Because the Pod IP is not important and service IP is important.

So If it is possible? If yes, please suggest how to configure other microservice to register its kubernetes service IP and not the pod IP with Eureka.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eureka and Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567429/eureka-and-kubernetes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Netflix Eureka can be used with kubernetes. The thing how it will work is, All the pods try to register itself with Eureka and Also discover other services from Eureka. So here the kubernetes services IP won't be used by the other pods and so don't get confused.

Also since multiple pods of the same service can register with Eureka by submitting their pod IP. So the Eureka will act as a load balancer.

Comment: so if it cant use service ip other services cant connect to pod using pod ip ?