# Zuul unable to route traffic to service on kubernetes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

We have Zuul and Eureka both up and running on our kubernetes cluster.  Zuul is registered with Eureka.

I start up a new service called "Resource-Service" this correctly boots up and registers with Eureka, all services are up.

When I attempt to hit Zuul endpoint to access "Resource-service" I get the following error.  Seems like Zuul can not map to Resource-service even though resource service is registered with eureka.

So how does zuul know where to route requests for "Resource-service" if not through a registered service in eureka?

Note: I have tried this with Docker-compose and was able to get to work, so must be something with kubernetes interacting with zuul and eureka.

**Zuul Stack Trace (Updated)**

```
2018-08-29 14:23:15.820  INFO 7 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-API-GATEWAY/zuul-api-gateway-79bd7d4c5-jgqxc:zuul-api-gateway:7100: registering service...
2018-08-29 14:23:15.916  INFO 7 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ZUUL-API-GATEWAY/zuul-api-gateway-79bd7d4c5-jgqxc:zuul-api-gateway:7100 - registration status: 204
2018-08-29 14:23:15.928  INFO 7 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 7100 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-29 14:23:15.929  INFO 7 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 7100
2018-08-29 14:23:15.934  INFO 7 --- [           main] n.e.m.z.ZuulApiGatewayApplication        : Started ZuulApiGatewayApplication in 11.624 seconds (JVM running for 12.771)
2018-08-29 14:27:59.166  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-29 14:27:59.175  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-08-29 14:27:59.249  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 73 ms
2018-08-29 14:27:59.504  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-1] o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/resource-service/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController]
2018-08-29 14:28:15.511  INFO 7 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2018-08-29 14:29:51.215  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] n.e.m.zuulapigateway.ZuulLoggingFilter   : zuul request uri -> /resource-service/resource/1
2018-08-29 14:29:51.219  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] n.e.m.zuulapigateway.JwtFilter           : auth:Bearer <<Removed>>
2018-08-29 14:29:51.277  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing SpringClientFactory-resource-service: startup date [Wed Aug 29 14:29:51 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@20322d26
2018-08-29 14:29:51.420  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-29 14:29:51.780  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: resource-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2018-08-29 14:29:51.805  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-resource-service
2018-08-29 14:29:51.952  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: resource-service instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=resource-service,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2018-08-29 14:29:51.964  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2018-08-29 14:29:52.045  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: resource-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2018-08-29 14:29:52.049  INFO 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client resource-service initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=resource-service,current list of Servers=[resource-service-7d9c6d6d99-j2mmv:10002],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;        Instance count:1;       Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;       Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:resource-service-7d9c6d6d99-j2mmv:10002;       Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout seconds:0;       Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970;   First connection made: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;   max resp time:0.0;      stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@1f11c5d0
2018-08-29 14:29:52.527  WARN 7 --- [nio-7100-exec-5] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:118) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar!/:1.5.12]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:159) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: resource-service-7d9c6d6d99-j2mmv: Name does not resolve
        at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: resource-service-7d9c6d6d99-j2mmv: Name does not resolve
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar!/:2.2.5]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
        ... 129 common frames omitted
```

**Eureka (Updated)**

[image]

**resource-service Bootstrap.yml (New)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: resource-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
      show_sql: true #WARNING: set this to false for production
      format_sql: true #WARNING: set this to false for production
      hbm2ddl:
        auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  eureka:
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: true
    client:
      registerWithEureka: true
      fetchRegistry: true
  example:
    property: "RESOURCE SERVICE DEV PROFILE TEST"

#logging.level.root: debug
```

**zuul-api-gateway (bootstrap.yml)**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-api-gateway
  server:
    port: 7100
  profiles:
    active: default
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
zuul:
  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true
```

**Kubectl get all**

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you've a mismatch between the host name being registered to Zuul and the one on which the service is reachable in k8s. Do 'kubectl get services' to find the names of your k8s services. Zuul will get the name that is registered to it from eureka (it seems you are registering names and not IPs). If you change the name of your Service in your k8s yaml for resource-service to be 'resource-service' then I'd expect it to work.

In your docker-compose I expect you have a section that defines the resource-service and it is presumably named resource-service. The equivalent for k8s is the name of the Service that matches to the Pods of that particular Deployment.

Edit: A spring boot app by default registers with eureka the Pod's hostname (if not using IP). So to override this it's necessary to set eureka.instance.hostname to match the Service name.

Comment: Thank you, we didn't have the service exposed and zuulgateway was not named correctly in application.name  However now we do and gotten the same error.  I have added additional screen shots to the question above.

Comment: Updated to add kubectl get all command and also our bootstrap.yml for both services.

Comment: Could you try with preferIpAddress false in bootstrap of the resource-service? I suspect the problem now relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567429/eureka-and-kubernetes

Comment: No go, same result.  What else can I show you to shed some light on this?  If the Application is registered with eureka.  I exec'd into eureka and curled to resource-service and did get a response.

Comment: Actually there is a clue in the error message. It says `resource-service-7d9c6d6d99-j2mmv: Name does not resolve`. That is the pod name and not the service name. I think to override this you need to set `eureka: instance: hostname: resource-service` in your resource-service application.yaml (with proper indenting). I had assumed this was spring.application.name so I may need to update my answer as I think I was wrong on this. Be sure to restart everything.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this issue.  We ended up setting a manual routing in zuul, maybe we will revisit this in the future, but its working for now.

Comment: A related question on this with more clarification is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019101/how-to-access-each-other-between-k8s-and-microservices

Comment: A clarification to @RyanDawson answer - In the k8s deployment.yml of the concerned component (resource server), adding the property EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME=<k8s-service-name as mentioned in the resource servers service.yml> helped. However, in the eureka web-page, the name registered is still in the name of the deployment, and not the name specified in the property above! Still it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I went to deploy eureka server and zull proxy to the Google Kubernet Cluster, the solution is divided into two part :
**first part:** client side as mentioned we need to add : eureka: instance: hostname: resource-service .
**second part:** is Eureka server deployment, in kubernet we should use statfulset as a kind of deployment to guarantee stable network . **you find below me eureka yml deployment :**

```
              ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka-server
  labels:
    app: eureka-server
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    name: eureka-server
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: eureka-server
---    
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eureka-server
spec:
  serviceName: "eureka-server"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eureka-server
        image: # eureka image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
          # Due to camelcase issues with "defaultZone" and "preferIpAddress", _JAVA_OPTIONS is used here
        - name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
          value: -Deureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false -Deureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-0.eureka-server:9000/eureka/
        - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_REGISTERWITHEUREKA
          value: "true"
        - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_FETCHREGISTRY
          value: "true"
        # The hostnames must match with the the eureka serviceUrls, otherwise the replicas are reported as unavailable in the eureka dashboard      
        - name: EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME
          value: ${MY_POD_NAME}.eureka-server
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Zuul registers with Eureka makes Zuul a client of Eureka.

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
**eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true**
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

**fetchRegistry** property enables Zuul (as a client of Eureka) to fetch the registry directory i.e. list of registered services in Eureka.

Once the Zuul server is up, you can see which routes are open using http://localhost:8762/routes url.

These routes were created by Zuul through fetched registry and relevant service ids. You can change the routes for every service id the way you want by configuring each service id in Zuul application properties i.e.

```
zuul.routes.student-service.path=/student-api/**
zuul.routes.student-service.serviceId=STUDENT-SERVICE
```

Also, the preferable way is to rely on IPs and not host names. i.e. use preferIpAddress property as suggested by others in other answers.