# Using Netflix Eureka on Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

We are currently setting up a Micro-service Architecture using spring boot and netflix components, for Deployment we are planning to go with aws kubernetes(EKS) setup. We are in a  in a dilemma to choose whether to use netflix's Eureka & ribbon services on Kubernetes for service discovery or to use Kubernetes own service discovery Mechanism. The advantages I see in using k8s service discovery is that horizontal scaling becomes easy. Any thoughts on this will be really good for us to take it in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a strong case for client side load balancing I would not use Eureka and ribbon. I am getting the load balancing and service discovery from my platform (k8s) for free. If not for client side load balancing, there is no value that eureka and ribbon brings other than beefing up your resume :). On the other hand, it brings another stack that you need to maintain in the long term.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568412/6785908) is a kind of related question